# Please merge the 30-year-war tag into the Thirty Years' War tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-merge

A recent question was tagged [30-year-war](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/30-year-war), but there is also  a [thirty-years-war](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thirty-years-war) tag and the former should be merged into the latter. Since there are so many questions with the former I guess an alias is in order.

I'd always heard it called the "Thirty Years' War" ([and Google Ngrams backs this up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thirty+years+war%2Cthirty+year+war%2C30+years+war%2C30+year+war&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthirty%20years%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThirty%20Years%20War%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthirty%20years%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTHIRTY%20YEARS%20WAR%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThirty%20Years%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThirty%20years%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthirty%20year%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BThirty%20Year%20War%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthirty%20year%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C30%20years%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B30%20years%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B30%20Years%20War%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B30%20years%20War%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C30%20year%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B30%20year%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B30%20Year%20War%3B%2Cc0)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the way I'd always heard it too. Just as a sanity check, "[Thirty Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War)" is how it is in Wikipedia as well.

IMHO, the "30 year war" variant is wrong enough that it wouldn't really help anyone out as a synonym, so its 4 questions should just be retagged properly (to the other tag name). After a week or 3 with nothing tagged that way, it should disappear on its own.

Comment: I don’t know why, but I thought there were dozens. As penance, I did the retagging.

Comment: @Spencer-   I don't even think there's a dozen between the two.

Comment: @TED Is it worth adding a [tag:status-completed] tag to the Q?

Comment: @Spencer - Looks good to me, and its your question, so feel free. :-)

Comment: I mean ... someone sufficiently motivated could probably elaborate on the tag wiki a bit. But that's outside of the scope of this particular question.

Comment: @TED Not a mod, so I can't add that one. Anyway, A lot of people type digits when something begins with a number. So a [tag:30-years-war] tag synonym might still be useful, just because of the way tag autocomplete works.

Comment: @Spencer - There's probably a rep requirement, but I don't think one needs to be a diamond mod to edit a tag wiki?